# Server-client communication by using IP address doesn't work

Tags: java, sockets, stream, client-server, buffer

Server application and client application are running in different computers. I want to send some message from client to server. The server should receive it and display. But in my case it's not happening. Nothing happens in server computer when something is sent.

This is my client program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class EchoClient {
    //private static final String IP="194.47.46.36";

    public EchoClient() {

    }
    public void establish() {
        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {

            //echoSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8080);
            echoSocket = new Socket("195.47.46.76", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;
        try {
            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(userInput);
                if (userInput.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
                System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            stdIn.close();
            echoSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
            System.exit(
                    -1);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the *external* IP address. If that's what you meant to use, then it needs to be forwarded to the server's computer. This is done on the router. If you meant to use the internal IP, you should use `ifconfig` (Linux/Mac) or `ipconfig` (Windows) on the server machine to find what it is.